# Conditional variable (counters) defined in a command called from a figure behaves as it was automatically defined before

Tags: floats, conditionals, counters, floatrow, variable

I recently try to generalise a command working with footnotemark and footnotetext. 
For that, I work with a conditional call that defined a counter, which serves as a testing of previous calls.

I have run into some problem with the structure of the test, but it was solved in another question on stackexchange. But now I run into a weirder problem. The conditional test seems to run differently if the commands are called from a caption of a figure or from a text. And I don't see why.

More weirdly, it behaves differently if it is called from a classic figure or from a figure using ffimgbox.

Here the testing code to illustrate the problem : (i use tux.png for the testing : https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Tux.png)

```
%%%%%%%%%%% LOT OF PACKAGES AND DEFINITIONS %%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,final, DIV=12, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, toc=bibliography, open=right, chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[greek,english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[final]{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotehyper}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[format=plain, font=small, labelfont=bf, textfont=it]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
\usepackage[float=false]{scrhack}

%%%%%%%%%%% LOT OF PACKAGES AND DEFINITIONS END %%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%% BEGENNING OF THE WORK ON FOOTNOTES %%%%%%%%%%

%%% Counter for making unique ID for the footnotemark and footnotetext without [] %%%%%%
\newcounter{myHyperFootnoteCounterMARK}
%%%%% Counter for testing in which branch of testing we go  %%%%%%
\newcounter{lalala}
%
\makeatletter

%%%%% define an new footnote with optional argument : the IF never reach the undefined case, the counter "lala" is never incrememented and "BA" is only shown in the text : i have tested diverses formulation \@ifundefined \ifcsname etc etc... %%%%%
\newcommand{\myOptHyperFootnotetext}[2][plop]{
    \def\myFootnoteTagtextARGU{hfoi:#1}
    \def\mysavee{saved@Href@#1}
    %
    \ifcsname c@counter@Href:#1\endcsname
    % CASE DEFINED
        AA\thelalala
        %
        \expandafter\let\expandafter\Hy@footnote@currentHref\csname\mysavee\endcsname%
        \footnotetext{\hyperref[\myFootnoteTagtextARGU]{$\uparrow$}~#2}%
        %   
    \else 
    % CASE UNDEFINED
        AB\stepcounter{lalala}
        %
        \expandafter\let\expandafter\Hy@footnote@currentHref\csname\mysavee\endcsname
        \footnotetext{\hyperref[\myFootnoteTagtextARGU]{$\uparrow$}~#2}
        %definition of the counter if it is undifined
        \newcounter{counter@Href:#1}
        %   
    \fi
}

\newcommand{\myOptHyperFootnotemark}[1][plop]{%
    \def\myFootnoteTagtextargu{hfoi:#1}%
    \def\mysave{saved@Href:#1}%
    %
    \ifcsname c@counter@Href:#1\endcsname
        % CASE DEFINED
        BA\thelalala
        %
        \label{\myFootnoteTagtextargu}
        \footnotemark \global\expandafter\let\csname\mysave\endcsname\Hy@footnote@currentHref%
    \else   
    % CASE UNDEFINED
        BB\stepcounter{lalala}
        \label{\myFootnoteTagtextargu}
        \footnotemark \global\expandafter\let\csname\mysave\endcsname\Hy@footnote@currentHref%  
        %definition of the counter if it is undifined
        \newcounter{counter@Href:#1}
        %
    \fi
}
%
\makeatother



%%%%%%% some package %%%%%%%
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

%%%%%% begin %%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%% TEST %%%%%%

\chapter{TEST}
\section{Introduction}

Texttest

%%%%%%%% uncomment this to test the code when it works outisde the figure %%%%%%%%
%\myOptHyperFootnotemark[truc] 

%%%%%%%% Uncomment to test the code in a classic figure %%%%%%%%
%\begin{figure}[h]
%\centering
%\includegraphics{Tux.png}
%\caption{A caption \myOptHyperFootnotemark[truc]}
%\label{Tux}
%\end{figure}

%%%%%%%% The code calling from the caption inside a floatrow %%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}[ht]
   \centering
   {
     \begin{floatrow}[1]
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption[blaa]{\label{Tino} BLAAAAA \myOptHyperFootnotemark[truc]}}%
{\includegraphics{Tux.png}}.
     \end{floatrow}
   }
\end{figure}

EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

\myOptHyperFootnotetext[truc]{A footnote}% 

\end{document}
```

In theory, the call of myOptHyperFootnotemark before myOptHyperFootnotetext should lead to the creation of the counter "counter@Href:truc" and to the incrementation of the counter "lala" which serve here as a testing for the call of these function. 0 for lala = never called the creation of the counter and other number -> creation was called.

And it works in the uncomment part of the code called from a text. We obtain "BB" in the text (which means : "I am in the assignment block of the function") and "AA1" in the footnote (which means : the counter with that name has already been assigned, so I am in the unassigned block).
This is the result wanted and it's logical, this also prove that the testing works.

But if you do the same in a figure, the result is not the same (commented part of the code to uncomment for testing). In a classical figure, we obtain "BA1" in the text and "AA1" in the footnote. Which both mean : at another point the code to create the variable was called, but it is not here (but where ? ... ) .

The result is even stranger if you called it in a floatrow environment (which is my goal) as it shows BA0 and AA0 which mean " We never called the assignation function but we pass the testing of the existence of the counter anyway ... "

This last variant is very weird for me and I don't really understand how it could be possible ...

I take any help ;)

Comment: you are issuing \newcounter within a group, that is almost always wrong, as it will go out of scope. The counters should be allocated initially at the start, not within the document on each footnote text.

Comment: You are not taking into account that the code is processed more than once for measuring. In the normal figure caption sets it twice (you can avoid this with `singlelinecheck=false`).  floatrow processed the content even three times - and it certainly has code to correctly reset the counters. Latex maintains a list of counters (\cl@@ckpt) which such packages use to reset them after they have done multiple processing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So if i want to pass a value from a function called within a group to a function called outside a group is it possible by any mean? Here i tried to play on the fact that i have an ID in common that i write inside the two function manually, like the « label/ref » mechanism. Is it impossible to reproduce this mecanism ? 
In theory it should be possible to declare a global variable from the inside of a group non ?
Beside, notice here that the counter used for check the passage in branches (lala), for testing, is declared globaly. Why is it at 0 with the floatrow environement ?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your answer. So if i want to conserve a value in that case, it is impossible ? No way to declare a global counter in a function called from inside a group ?
For example, the label/ref mecanism appear to work well in that case, is it an ad-hoc mechanism impossible te reproduce ? 
The initial goal here is to retain the value of the counter "footnote" in these function, but only once to have a coherent drawing of the footnote number. The idea at the begenning was to use a shared counter for that. Is is absolutly impossible here ?

Comment: Sorry I have no really idea what you are trying to do and why you think you can achieve it by creating new counters on the fly (label/ref doesn't do this).

Comment: to be honest it's a bit hard to tell your intention i was just commenting on the use of `\newcounter` plain tex makes such use impossible by declaring it `\outer` latex relaxes that but declaring counters on use is usually wrong even so,  your example document has lots of complicated code like \usepackage{import}
\usepackage{subcaption}  \usepackage{floatrow} etc that seems unrelated to the issue but makes it a lot harder to trace what is happening while you describe some counter use  you mainly describe it as being "strange" which isn't helpful.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer just said the same, but in fewer words

Comment: "I recently try to generalise a command working with footnotemark and footnotetext. " what is the generalisation that you want to achieve?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The goal was to allow the call of a footnotemark[label] footnotetext[label] in the document and letting the function make the good numerotation.
The idea is based on a tricks given in hyperref documentation about footnotemark and footnotetext that allow their use with hyperref. 
The system work with hyperref and even with backref in and outside figure and other environnement but rely on some "setcounter" in the text to achieve the good number.
My idea here was to use a flag to remember automaticaly the state of the counter "footnote" to have both function works.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : [...] to achieve this i needed to declare a variable shared by the two function (with their argument).
Of course, as the two functions could be called in disorder the point here is to have a variable that can save the footnote counter AND be allocated only once for the two function : counter seems to have the both advantages as they can save the value of an other counter and as their existence can be test before (as in this code). And it works, in text, not in figure. 

For the diverses package, their are not usefull, i will make a bit of clean and edit the example.

Comment: but it seems you just want (at most) one counter to shadow the footnote counter so you only need to allocate one extra counter, why are you allocating a counter within the footnote itself??? You refer to hyperref but hyperref never does that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Becaus i have to save the value of the footnote counter even if footnotemark is called several time and footnotetext several time, even in disorder. So i have to retain the value of the footnote counter before each footnotemark (as other function could use the counter between two call).
Of course, any variable able to save a value would do the tricks, as long as they are global.
For hyperref, you can see the "nasty example" at the page 51 of the hyperref as an example of how to do that manually : 
http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf

Comment: A variable (or a key in a property list) would make much more sense than creating a counter each time only to store one value. You can run tests on the existence and the content of such variables in quite a similar way. You can even save them with e.g. zref in the aux-file so that you have a list you can inspect at the next compilation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok, i have modified my code in that way. And it works in a lot of way. But the core of the problem is the same : if i create a simple command like \ifcsname r@mylabel \endcsname bla \else \label{mylabel} \fi and call that command from a figure, it will always say that "there were multidefined label". It prevent me from, for example, testing if a function is called twice with the same argument as long as one of the call is made in a caption...
And the problem is exactly the same with \immediate\write\@auxout{...}

Comment: @UlrikeFischer secondpart of message : [...] Of course i imagine it's not a fatality as a simple \label in a caption will works without complaining about multiple definition. But how to achieve the same result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full answer of this question was given by @frougon in this question : 
[How to make a robust conditional labeling that resist multiple compilation and figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533647/how-to-make-a-robust-conditional-labeling-that-resist-multiple-compilation-and-f)

It is a bit technical but it works (on counter or label or whatever).

Please report to this page to have the full answer ;)