# How to make a robust conditional labeling that resist multiple compilation and figures?

Tags: compiling, conditionals, labels

I have created a question [previously](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533427/conditional-variable-counters-defined-in-a-command-called-from-a-figure-behave) about my code, but it was too big and fuzzy to isolate properly my problematic (and the code have changed meanwhile). 
Here's a new version of my question on very simple toys example that make it more precise and very short.

I try to make a function that can be called with the same argument like :

```
\myFunction{foo} some text \myFunction{foo}
```

but i need that this function give a different result in the second case and, in addition, that a label is defined only in the first case (in order that a "\ref" reference only to the first call of the command).

The result needed :

```
"Foo is OK and labeled" some text "you have defined foo before, this is not labeled" !
```

I have tried several things that do not give this result robustly. The result tends to be different depending on environments or/and on multiple compilations.

I tried to use the label mechanism because it has some warning integrated that are useful and as it seems like \label{foo} create a variable r@foo I wrote :

```
\newcommand{\MyTesting}[1]
{
    \ifcsname r@#1\endcsname
        Already defined
    \else
        \label{#1}
    \fi
}
```

The result of this is ... strange, as it seems that label write in the aux file (or other file like this) a simple call like :

```
\MyTesting{test}
```

will give through the successive compilations :

1. **Label may have changed, rerun to get crossreference right**
2. nothing
3. **Label may have changed, rerun to get crossreference right**
4. nothing
5. etc...

So, the result seems to change one compilation in two, which is not the result desired.

But yet, at this point it's not critical. Let's test it with :

```
\MyTesting{test} some text \MyTesting{test}
```

Here we have, through the successive compilation :

1. **Label may have changed, rerun to get crossreference right**
2. **Label 'test' multiply defined**
3. **Label may have changed, rerun to get crossreference right**
4. **Label 'test' multiply defined**
5. etc...

Here I don't really get the logic... even if the label is saved in the aux, the test at the beginning of the \MyTesting should prevent the multiple definition.

**Bonus criteria for the answers : The call of the function should also be robust through environnement like caption in «figure» that seems to be evaluated twice ....**

I take any help on this problem ;)

The MWE :

```
%%%% work with koma-script, should also work on standard classes %%%%
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}  

\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} % only for testing
\usepackage{floatrow} % for testing
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MyLabel}[1]
{
    \ifcsname r@#1\endcsname
        Already defined
    \else
        \label{#1}
    \fi
} 
\makeatother

%%%%%% begin %%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%% TEST %%%%%%

\chapter{TEST}
\section{Introduction}

Try to label a first time \MyLabel{Firsttest}
Try to label a second time with the same \MyLabel{Firsttest}

%%% for testing in a caption, you can uncomment this part of code %%%

%\begin{figure}[h]
%\centering
%\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{images/Tux.png}
%\caption{A caption}%
%\end{figure}

%%% for testing in a floatrow, you can uncomment this part of code %%%

%\begin{figure}[ht]
%   \centering
%   {
%     \begin{floatrow}[1]
%        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{A caption}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/Tux.png}}
%     \end{floatrow}
%   }
%\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm. Basically you seem to want to reproduce the "first use" and "use" tests of packages like acro or glossaries.

Comment: you are testing "has it been defined on a previous run, if so do not define it" not "has it been defined earlier in the document"  so it is defined on even runs and not defined on odd ones.

Comment: @frougon : OK, thank you for explaining the logic. Here the goal is to have a function which could be called twice (or more) but with only label with this name on the first function.
May be i should define an other variable and not do the testing on the label ?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : exactly. Maybe i should take a look in their code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test of `\r@label` tests whether the label is already defined *according to the `.aux` file*. Indeed, `\label` writes `\newlabel` calls to the `.aux` file. This `.aux` file is read:

- at `\enddocument` time, which allows LaTeX to warn about multiply-defined labels;
- at begin document time, which allows the `\newlabel` calls present in the `.aux` file to define `\r@label` for each label that was defined with `\label` during the previous compilation run.

Thus:

1. When your macro finds `\r@test` defined, it means it called `\label{test}` in the **previous compilation run**; it will print “already defined” and **won't call** `\label{test}` in this run, and this holds for *all* invocations of your macro with argument `test` during this compilation run.
2. The next time you compile, the `.aux` file won't have any `\newlabel` call for label `test`, thus your macro will always find that `\r@test` isn't defined and will always call `\label{test}` in this compilation run, hence the “Label 'test' multiply defined” warning output every time your macro is called with argument `test` during this compilation run. The `\label{test}` calls write `\newlabel` calls for `test` to the `.aux` file, therefore on the next compilation run, we'll be back to step 1.

I believe that what you want is the following. The `\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect` test allows us to make sure nothing leaks to figure captions *in the list of tables or list of figures* (the test is true during typesetting, but not when captions are written to the `.lot` or `.lof` files via `\addtocontents`—the latter uses `\protected@write`, which temporarily makes `\protect` `\let`-equal to `\@unexpandable@protect`).

Edit: well, due to how `floatrow` works, dealing with `\MyLabel` inside a caption for `floatrow` is much more complicated than that, but the following appears to work fine. Note that several compilation runs are needed for labels to stabilize.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{graphicx} % only for testing
\usepackage{floatrow} % only for testing

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myInit}[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\newcounter{mycount@##1}}%
  \docsvlist{#1}%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
      \ifcsundef{my@goodvalue@##1}{\def\@currentlabel{??}\label{##1}}{}}%
    \docsvlist{#1}%
  }%
}

\newcommand*{\my@MaybeDefine}[2]{%
  \ifcsundef{my@goodvalue@#1}{\csgdef{my@goodvalue@#1}{#2}}{}%
}

\newcommand*{\my@WriteCtr}[2]{%
  \write\@auxout{\string\my@MaybeDefine{#1}{#2}}%
}

\newcommand*{\MyLabel}[2]{%
  \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
    \stepcounter{mycount@#1}%
    \edef\my@internal@label{my@internal@label@#1@\number\value{mycount@#1}}%
    \ifcsdef{my@goodvalue@#1}
      {\ifnum\value{mycount@#1}=\csuse{my@goodvalue@#1}
        \refstepcounter{#2}%
        \label{#1}%
       \else
         \IfRefUndefinedBabel{#1}{}{% Ref #1 is defined
           \IfRefUndefinedBabel{\my@internal@label}
             {}
             {%
               \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{\my@internal@label}=\getpagerefnumber{#1}
                 the special label is defined earlier on the same page%
               \else
                   \ifnum\getpagerefnumber
                           {\my@internal@label}>\getpagerefnumber{#1}
                     the special label was defined on an earlier page%
                   \fi
               \fi
             }%
         }%
       \fi
      }
      {\typeout{You need to rerun LaTeX for the special labels.}}%
    \label{\my@internal@label}%
    \begingroup
      \edef\tmp{\endgroup\noexpand\my@WriteCtr{#1}{\number\value{mycount@#1}}}%
    \tmp
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\myInit{First-test, Second-test} % The special labels

\newcounter{example}
\setcounter{example}{0}         % not really needed: this is done implicitly

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Introduction}

Try to label a first time\MyLabel{First-test}{example}.
Try to label a second time with the same: \MyLabel{First-test}{example}.

Label \verb|First-test| is on page~\pageref{First-test} and corresponds to
value~\ref{First-test} of the \verb|example| counter. Label \verb|Second-test|
is on page~\pageref{Second-test} and corresponds to value~\ref{Second-test} of
the \verb|example| counter.

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A caption.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[p]
  \centering
   Some floating material that will appear late in the PDF output:
   \MyLabel{Second-test}{example}.%
   \label{a-table}%
   \caption{A table environment}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{floatrow}[1]
     \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
       {\caption{Another caption\MyLabel{Second-test}{example}}}
       {\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-b}}
  \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

Calling \verb|\MyLabel{Second-test}{example}| a third time:
\MyLabel{Second-test}{example}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

## How it works

Beware, this is a bit technical. The main problem we had with `floatrow` is that it typesets the caption text many times with `\protect` equal to `\@typeset@protect` (5 times for a single caption in my test!). In fact, it appears to measure it in a few ways before deciding to ship it out. So, for each particular *special label* (those declared with `\myInit` and used in `\MyLabel`), we need to detect the first time where it is shipped out (i.e., sent to the DVI or PDF file) and *only for this time* use `\label`. For earlier times, we must output nothing (otherwise, we could disturb the measurements) and for later times, we need to output “already defined” as requested in the question, but no `\label` call.

Now, how does `\MyLabel` detect when a given label is being shipped out for the first time? For each label, it counts the number of times it is called in typesetting mode (`\protect` equal to `\@typeset@protect`) and `\write`s the corresponding value of the counter to the `.aux` file (this is the `value` in `\my@MaybeDefine{special label}{value}`). This is the main trick. A `\write` is a *whatsit* (cf. TeXbook), thus something that gets inside boxes, and *it only results in an actual write to a file if the box containing the whatsit is shipped out*. So, the dummy calls used by `floatrow` or other packages for measuring the caption text and whatnot get handled this way: no ship out, no writing to the `.aux` file. The `value` in the first `\my@MaybeDefine{special label}{value}` written to the `.aux` file indicates the first time `\MyLabel` was used with first argument `special label` inside a box that was shipped out. So, when the internal counter for `special label` is equal to this first value, assuming the source file didn't change since the last compilation, this means the material containing `special label` is being typeset “for real” for the first time.

One more thing: because of floats (tables, figures...), it is possible that some material associated to a *special label* be typeset (even with `\protect` equal to `\@typeset@protect`) earlier than the `\label` command for the *special label*, but appear later in the output file. In such cases, the internal counter associated to the *special label* would have a value that is lower than the “good value“ when the material  is being typeset for the early float, but still, it needs the “already defined” text since the material will appear later than the `\label`. For this reason, I added internal labels and when the internal counter is different from the “good value,” I compare the page on which the internal label appears, if it appears at all, to the page where the `\label{special label}` is found. When contents is not shipped out (`floatrow` doing measurements, etc.), the corresponding internal labels don't get defined, thus the text, which I modified to “the special label is defined earlier on the same page” and “the special label was defined on an earlier page” doesn't disturb the measurements (see the code).

Yes, this is a bit hackish!

Comment: I've completed the example to show you where to put the `\refstepcounter` call for the `\label` command used in `\MyLabel` (if you put `\refstepcounter` straight in the `\caption` mandatory argument, it won't work).

Comment: It is almost perfect thanks ! "Almost" because it works in all case EXCEPT, partially, in the floatrow case. in the floatrow case, if i use your command to label a first time before the floatrow and a second time in the floatrow caption i obtain : "defined" (in the text or the previous figure) and "already defined" (in the floatrow caption). But if i use the function in the floatrow first and in a text bellow in second, i obtain "already defined" / " already defined" and so it fails in this specific case...
No luck for me, it is the main case of application in my case :p

Comment: Didn't understand well the refstepcounter modification in your new example. The \ref command will not work as usal without it ?

Comment: `\ref` works as shown by the new example. I'm investigating your first comment... This may be due to the asynchronous nature of `figure`.

Comment: This is difficult. I believe `floatrow`typesets the same caption several times with `\protect` set as `\@typeset@protect` (five times according to my test!). The first time, the label is set... but this is probably in `\sbox` and the boxed is not shipped out, therefore the label is not written to the `.aux` file. The other times, our `\my@label@#1` sentinel is defined, therefore we always output “already defined” from this point on. So, the first time wasn't really used for typesetting but probably for measuring, that is our problem. I'll delete the answer unless I find a workaround.

Comment: OK, thank you for looking at it. You could let your original answer here, no problem if it's only partial, it is usefull. You can post a second answer later ;)

Comment: Thank you for the work you have done ;) It really help me for the other cases ;) 
I think your answer is OK for my question. May be i should open a new question more specialised with floatrow ? 
Don't know if i could get more specialised help if i ask specifially on floatrow ... ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. It now appears to work fine even inside the mandatory argument of `floatrow`'s `\caption`. Please try it out. :-)

Comment: Note: with the new technique, what counts for the "first use which sets the label" is where the material appears *in the output file*. For instance, if a figure or table (i.e., a float) appears early in the .tex file but late in the output file, other things occurring earlier in the output, even if later in the source, would be chosen for writing the `\label` command. If this is not how you want it, this technique isn't suitable. I hope not...

Comment: What an awesome work ! And it really work :p ! Great job and thanks. But i have a question about the working of your tricks. If i understand well, here, the function is called several times by floatrow (or other environnement) that call it during typesetting, and only at the last typesetting the write is called and write the counter for this.
Ok, this, i understand. But how the code could enter in the \ifcsdef{my@goodvalue@#1} ? as this require that the write have been done AND to be in the typesetting (which seems note possible as the write is in the end of the function)...

Comment: Thanks. Don't forget that the .aux file is executed before the `\AtBeginDocument` hook. So, any `\my@MaybeDefine` command that was previously written to the .aux can define the macro before we get to the test you mentioned (but for a given label, only the first `\my@MaybeDefine` will do something: this is the one that gives us the "good value" of the counter. :)

Comment: by "previously writen" i imagine you mean : at the previous compilation ? If i understand, the counting is done at the first compilation then saved in the aux and then used at the second compilation to find the first label called ?
If that is the case i (again :p ) miss something. During the first compilation all the mylabel(foo) function that are called during typesetting are called i guess ? So why the counter don't take the sum of ALL of them? (for example, if the mylabel is typeset 5 time in the first mylabel, and 2 in the second mylabel, the counter should be 7 and the test should fail).

Comment: I think i get it after some reflexion :p : the "write" instruction is set at each call and it stack in the aux, so we have many "\my@MaybeDefine{foo}{X}". And it is the first one which is really set due to the ifcsundef in \my@MaybeDefine. Until this point i am OK so. 
An other question : why the init is needed, i don't get that ... i think the creation of the counter can be done at the first call of the function and i really don't get what is the point of the "\def\@currentlabel{??}\label{##1}" executed for each argument of the list... commenting this line seems to don't change the result .

Comment: I updated the code to cope with the asynchronous nature of floats (see the update). What you wrote is mostly correct, but if you suppress the line you said and remove the .aux file, you'll get a `LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references` because the special `\label` call isn't output on the first run, since we don't know the “good value“ yet. So, the purpose of the `\ifcsundef{my@goodvalue@##1}{\def\@currentlabel{??}\label{##1}}{}}` is to define the *special labels* during the first run.

Comment: The code works perfectly and i have adapted it in my case of application, it work very well (and it don't really need the init so it make it very versatile and usefull ! ).
I really thinks this code should be available as a standard function as the environnement like floatrow are common ...

Comment: Thanks for your kind feedback, that's always good to hear.